# tabular* makecell + \textwidth to have line breaks and span

Tags: tables, width

I would like to have a table span the text but allow for line breaks (using makecell). The table spans (because the lines go to the end), but the text is not spread out correctly (i.e. as I would like). Here is minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\caption{test table}

\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{lcccccccc}
  \hline
\hline
col 1 & A & \makecell[tc]{B\\C} & D & \makecell[tc]{E\\f} & \makecell[tc]{G\\ hij} & \makecell[tc]{K\\ lmn} & \makecell[tc]{O\\ P} & \makecell[tc]{Q\\ R} \\ 
  \hline
testing1 &  1 &   2 &   3 &   4 &  5 &  6 &   7 &  8 \\ 
testing2 &   9 &   10 &   11 &   12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It gives the following:

[image]

I would like for the text to be spread out across the table. But it is shifted towards the right.

I have a program that creates the above LaTeX so I'm looking for a solution where I do not need to change too much otherwise I will have to spend a lot of time rewriting the program.

Comment: Why not using `tabularx`?

Comment: @SalimBou would I have to change a lot to use it? Or just replace "tabular*" with "tabularx"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\makecell` has nothing to do with the problem. You are not setting `\extracolsep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\caption{test table}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}
  lcccccccc
}
\hline
\hline
col 1 & A & \makecell[tc]{B\\C} & D & \makecell[tc]{E\\f} & \makecell[tc]{G\\ hij} & \makecell[tc]{K\\ lmn} & \makecell[tc]{O\\ P} & \makecell[tc]{Q\\ R} \\ 
\hline
testing1 &  1 &   2 &   3 &   4 &  5 &  6 &   7 &  8 \\ 
testing2 &   9 &   10 &   11 &   12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]